# What is the best way to score a relationship using Opengraph endpoints?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I want to score a relationship between two people, a sort of index or meta point score based on a number of factors.

These factors include:

- Number of mutual friends
- Number of mutual movie likes
- Number of mutual music likes
- Number of photos both are tagged in
- Number of posts to and from one another

Using Opengraph and the Facebook API/SDK I cannot find a way to easily attain the last two of the above points. The first 3 should be easily attainable with endpoints such as: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-context/

So, how would I easily get those figures in as few API calls as possible?

Comment: Not entirely sure why this has been downvoted and has a close vote.